# Algebraic Relationships in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

so i am learning about algebraic relationships in database programming where we are using mysql. So lets say that we have these tables:

```
Supermarket (Shop_no, shop_name, location, manager_number) 
Manager (manager_number, manager_name, salary)
```

An i need to obtain the shop name and location of all those shops where the shop manager earns $20,000 or more. So to does this i would do something like this:

```
Select manager where salary ≥ $20,000 giving T1 
Join T1, Supermarket over manager_no giving T2 
Project T2 over shop_name, location giving result
```

So my question is, this is all good on paper, but how would i go about doing this in mysql? I tried to do the same thing on MYSQL but i keep getting the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T1' at line 1
```

Which would mean that either mysql does something different to get the same results or im doing something wrong.

Comment: This is not MySQL syntax. Not a standard SQL either.

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: What language IS that, anyway?  I've never seen 'giving' and 'project' used that way.

Comment: That is the way i am currently being taught in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
SELECT shop_name, location FROM Supermarket s INNER JOIN 
Manager m ON  s.manager_number=m.manager_number WHERE m.salary ≥ 20,000
```